# Consuming WCF Services from SSIS

Tags: wcf, ssis

I am planning to consume a WCF Service from an SSIS Package, get the data and dump it to a table. Am planning to write the WCF Consumption part in the Script component part of the Data Control Flow Task, is that the best way to do things?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as i am totally new to SSIS

Regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [**link**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx) that shows `How to Configure an SSIS Package to Access a Web Service using WCF`. Hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: Thank you, i did try the same approach and got my service writing data to an XML but was wondering if this is the best way to go about things.